# relative size of most factors of semiprimes, close?

Tags: probability, number-theory, statistics, prime-numbers, semiprimes

when chatting about [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29) a cohort just asserted something like

> "most prime factors of [semiprimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) are roughly the same size" measured in bits.

ie "bits" is the number of digits in the base2 representations of the two primes. am skeptical myself. in other words, eg if a program filters the semiprimes from $1..n$ and then looks at the size of factors, the assertion is most will be approximately equal. his "proof" sketch was brief/hazy and unconvincing. am skeptical. have a different picture of this. (think it might be closer to *"many"*...)

> is this true? what is a proof sketch? is this connected to any number theory or area of study? if incorrect is there some other similar assertion that is correct?

Comment: What does "roughly the same size" mean? A factor of $2$ in bit-size, of $\frac32$, of $\frac98$? A difference of about $\sqrt{b}$ if $b$ is the size of one factor?

Comment: @daniel it was not formally stated, only informally, think the rough idea was something like "generally within a few bits size difference". (an answer might/could decide what the english words like "most" vs "many" mean formally via definition or whatever.)

Comment: @DanielFischer with high probability, it will be of similar size. That is, for example, something like $\frac{2^k-1}{2^k}$ chance of being within $k$ bits size of each-other or somesuch.

Comment: @vzn: The prime factors should differ by at least 100-bits. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5262/rsa-and-prime-difference

Comment: @Amzoti from [poncho's answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5265/2834): _"BTW: the recommendation $\Delta > 2^{k/2-100}$ doesn't mean 'p and q should differ by a number which is at least 100 bits long', it means closer to 'p and q should differ somewhere in their 100 most-significant bits'."_ i.e. it isn't talking about the difference in *bit-length*, as vzn is. Rather it is talking about having at least one different bit in one of upper significant bits.

Comment: I suggest you run a short program, a list of primes up to 5000, say, double loop so that you have all pairwise products up to 10000, that makes all your semiprimes. Sort these, then go back through, with some question in the program about how the sizes of the prime factors compare. Should tell you whether the comment is about random semiprimes or about semiprimes designed by humans.

Comment: @RealzSlaw: Yes, that is what I meant. There is awriteup in this in the Digital Signature Standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asymptotically, the proportion of semiprimes $\leqslant N$ where the two factors have roughly the same size is negligible, if we say that two primes $p \leqslant q$ have roughly the same size if there is a constant $\alpha > 1$ such that $q \leqslant p^\alpha$.

The number of semiprimes $\leqslant N$ is

$$\pi_{1/2}(N) = \sum_{p_k \leqslant \sqrt{N}} \left(\pi\left(\frac{N}{p_k}\right) - (k-1)\right),\tag{1}$$

and the number of semiprimes with two factors of $\alpha$-roughly the same size is

$$\pi_{1/2;\,\alpha}(N) = \sum_{p_k \leqslant N^{1/(\alpha+1)}} \left(\pi(p_k^\alpha) - (k-1)\right) + \sum_{N^{1/(\alpha+1)} \leqslant p_k \leqslant \sqrt{N}} \left(\pi\left(\frac{N}{p_k}\right) - (k-1)\right).\tag{2}$$

The sum of the subtracted terms is the same in both,

$$\frac{\pi(\sqrt{N})(\pi(\sqrt{N}-1)}{2} \sim \frac{2N}{(\log N)^2}.$$

In the first sum of $(2)$, we can estimate the contribution of the $\pi(p_k^\alpha)$ as

$$\sum_{p_k \leqslant N^{1/(\alpha+1)}} \pi(p_k^\alpha) \leqslant \pi(N^{1/(\alpha+1)})\cdot \pi(N^{\alpha/(\alpha+1)}) \sim \frac{(\alpha+1)^2 N}{\alpha(\log N)^2},$$

so it remains to consider

$$\sum_{A \leqslant p_k \leqslant B} \pi\left(\frac{N}{p_k}\right),\tag{3}$$

where here $B = \sqrt{N}$, and $A$ is either $2$ (for $(1)$), or $N^{1/(\alpha+1)}$ (for $(2)$).

To obtain the asymptotic behaviour, we don't need a too good approximation, $\pi(x) \sim x/\log x$ is sufficient. So

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{A \leqslant p_k \leqslant B} \pi\left(\frac{N}{p_k}\right)
&\approx \sum_{A\leqslant p_k\leqslant B} \frac{N}{p_k(\log N - \log p_k)}\\
&= \frac{N}{\log N} \sum_{A\leqslant p_k\leqslant B} \frac{1}{p_k\left(1 - \frac{\log p_k}{\log N}\right)}.
\end{align}$$

We have $0 < \log p_k \leqslant \frac12\log N$, and for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant \frac12$, we have $1+x \leqslant \frac{1}{1-x}\leqslant 1+x+2x^2$. Using further $p_k \sim k\cdot \log k$, the major term in the sum is

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{A \leqslant p_k \leqslant B} \frac{1}{p_k} &\sim \sum_{A\leqslant p_k\leqslant B} \frac{1}{k\log k}\\
&\sim \log \log \pi(B) - \log \log \pi(A).
\end{align}$$

For $(1)$, the sum is $\log \log N + O(1)$, while for $(2)$, the sum is $\log \frac{\alpha+1}{2} + O(1)$. For the next largest term, we get

$$\frac{1}{\log N}\sum_{A\leqslant p_k\leqslant B} \frac{\log p_k}{p_k} \approx \frac{1}{\log N}\sum_{A\leqslant p_k\leqslant B} \frac{1}{k} \approx \frac{\log (\pi(B)/\pi(A))}{\log N},$$

which is bounded, and similar for the $x^2$ term. So we have

$$\pi_{1/2}(N) \sim \frac{N\log \log N}{\log N},\tag{4}$$

and

$$\pi_{1/2;\,\alpha}(N) \sim c_\alpha\frac{N}{\log N} \in \Theta\left(\frac{N}{\log N}\right).\tag{5}$$

With more careful estimates, one can determine the constant $c_\alpha$, but the above is sufficient to see that asymptotically, almost all semiprimes $\leqslant N$ have factors of very different size.

However, the factor $\log \log N$ grows *very* slowly, so one needs to consider the semiprimes up to a really large limit for the proportion of semiprimes with two close factors to become negligible.

Obviously, I have neither the time nor the resources to compute the proportion for really large numbers, but the counts for small limits ($\alpha = 2$) already show a trend:

```
   Limit         Primes          Semiprimes        Close semiprimes
      100:       25 (1.1513)       34 (1.0253)      14 (0.6447; 41.1765)
      200:       46 (1.2186)       62 (0.9851)      22 (0.5828; 35.4839)
      500:       95 (1.1808)      153 (1.0409)      47 (0.5842; 30.7190)
     1000:      168 (1.1605)      299 (1.0687)      87 (0.6010; 29.0970)
     2000:      303 (1.1515)      577 (1.0811)     167 (0.6347; 28.9428)
     5000:      669 (1.1396)     1365 (1.0855)     377 (0.6422; 27.6190)
    10000:     1229 (1.1320)     2625 (1.0889)     693 (0.6383; 26.4000)
    20000:     2262 (1.1201)     5081 (1.0973)    1317 (0.6521; 25.9201)
    50000:     5133 (1.1108)    12110 (1.1004)    3115 (0.6741; 25.7225)
   100000:     9592 (1.1043)    23378 (1.1015)    5938 (0.6836; 25.3999)
   200000:    17984 (1.0976)    45230 (1.1033)   11339 (0.6920; 25.0696)
   500000:    41538 (1.0902)   108326 (1.1044)   26616 (0.6985; 24.5703)
  1000000:    78498 (1.0845)   210035 (1.1051)   50983 (0.7044; 24.2736)
  2000000:   148933 (1.0804)   407284 (1.1046)   97052 (0.7040; 23.8291)
  5000000:   348513 (1.0752)   979274 (1.1042)  230514 (0.7111; 23.5393)
 10000000:   664579 (1.0712)  1904324 (1.1041)  442445 (0.7131; 23.2337)
 20000000:  1270607 (1.0680)  3704340 (1.1034)  851642 (0.7159; 22.9904)
 50000000:  3001134 (1.0641)  8940570 (1.1025) 2024347 (0.7177; 22.6423)
100000000:  5761455 (1.0613) 17427258 (1.1019) 3904631 (0.7193; 22.4053)
200000000: 11078937 (1.0588) 33992717 (1.1011) 7534855 (0.7201; 22.1661)
```

The numbers in parentheses are

1. $\dfrac{\pi(x)\log x}{x}$,
2. $\dfrac{\pi_{1/2}(x)\log x}{x\log\log x}$,
3. $\dfrac{\pi_{1/2;\,2}(x)\log x}{x}$,
4. $\dfrac{100\cdot\pi_{1/2;\,2}(x)}{\pi_{1/2}(x)}$.

We see that $(4)$ is a decent asymptotic even for smallish numbers, while $(5)$ still has considerable fluctuation in the checked range, but we see that the proportion of semiprimes with two close factors drops steadily.