# All squarefree semiprime numbers that less than a certain number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, semiprimes

How can i find all number $N$, where $N=p*q$. (Here, $p$ and $q$ are primes and $p<q$) ?

For example: I want a formula that help me to find all $N<1000$

Comment: $1000$ is very small, it should be easy to compute the exact result in that case "by hand" (i.e., using a computer).  In general I do not believe you'll get anything like a closed formula.  Some bounds and asymptotic behavior for the function can be found, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619742/what-is-an-upper-bound-for-number-of-semiprimes-less-than-n)

Answer (score 2):

Apply the sieve of sundaram's logic, $$(2a+1)(2b+1)=2(2ab+a+b)+1$$ one of $a,b$ must  less than 16, because if not $a=b$ gives $$4a^2+4a+1>1000$$  Then applying it again you'll need $c$ less than 3, because you can sieve out all values that would not create primes in the product.  Finally you would double all primes less than 500.

Answer (score 1):

For each prime $p < \sqrt{1000}$, you take $pq$ for each prime $q$ with $p < q < 1000/p$.

EDIT:
As requested, here is some Matlab code.

```
A = tril(primes(500)' * primes(sqrt(1000)),-1);
sort(A(A > 0 & A < 1000)')
```

Comment: Can you write that as codes on MATLAB, please? I tried making that but i always had an error